# Sort array in alphabetic order without using Array.sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I want to sort values of an array in alphabetic order, using merge sort. I have this code so far, but I when I run it, the output is jumbled and not in correct order. (Charlottetown, Fredericton, Montreal, Toronto, Vancouver, ...)

If anyone has any advice/solutions, I would appreciate your help :)

Here is my current code.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] words = {
        "Montreal", "Halifax", "Toronto", "Vancouver",
        "Whitehorse", "Winnipeg", "Calgary", "Edmonton", 
        "Hamilton", "Regina", "Saskatoon", "Sault Ste. Marie", "Moncton", "Gander", "Fredericton", "Charlottetown"};
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        int smallest = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if(words[j].compareTo(words[i]) < 0)
                smallest = j;
        }       
        String aux = words[i];
        words[i] = words[smallest];
        words[smallest] = aux;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a merge sort :(  In any case, you need to step through the debugger to understand where you're going wrong (you *DO* have an IDE, and you *ARE* familiar with its debugger, right?)  SUGGESTION: Pay close attention to the values in the BOTTOM half of the array in LATER parts of your outer loop.  I suspect you're not swapping values that you need to...

Comment: *"If anyone has any advice/solutions, I would appreciate your help :)"* - My advice: use a debugger!  Or read / use https://rubberduckdebugging.com.   The point is that debugging is a skill that you need to learn.  For yourself.  And you learn it by doing it.

Comment: Hint, use a Comparator or Comparable and a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not merge sort this is actually selection sort (Don't worry there's so many sorting algorithms its easy to confuse them).

Secondly, Your issue here was you were only comparing the word at `word[i]` with every `word[j]` which won't sort correctly. Here is an example of what was happening:

**We have:**

```
String[] array = "Hippo, Alligator, Bear";
```

**With:**

```
if ( words[j].compareTo(words[i]) < 0 )
```

**Which translate to:**

```
if ( Alligator.compareTo(Hippo) < 0 )
```

**The result is:**

```
word[smallest] = Alligator
```

**But then it would run:**

```
if ( Bear.compareTo(Hippo) < 0 )
```

**And the final result is:**

```
word[smallest] = Bear
```

So it saves `Bear` as the `word[smallest]` but it should be `Alligator`. So instead of comparing `word[i]` with every `word[j]` you need to compare every `word[smallest]` with every `word[j]`. So you need to change `words[j].compareTo(words[i])` to `words[j].compareTo(words[smallest])`.